# Convert ISO 8061 datetime to timestamp in python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, iso8601

I have a string with a date in the format: `2021-03-12T14:45:34.000Z`

I would like to convert it to a standard format as this one: `12-Mar-2021 14:45:34`

I tried using:

```
print(datetime.datetime.strptime("2021-03-12T14:45:34.000Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%fZ"))
```

but I get the error:

> ValueError: time data '2021-03-12T14:45:34.000Z' does not match format
> '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%fZ'

How can I solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: If you use a literal Z in your parsing directive, make sure to be aware of the difference between naive and aware datetime in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `.` in your format string. The correct format string is

```
"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"
```

Notice the `.` after `%S` and before `%fZ`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get as `datetime` then convert to forrmat as you like:

```
import datetime

date = '2021-03-12T14:45:34.000Z'

datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"
                 ).strftime('%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Output:

```
'12-Mar-2021 14:45:34'
```

Comment: I got the error "AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'"

Comment: @Babbara, I use different import, edited answer, check now